# Websites for math tests/quizzes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, trigonometry, online-resources

Next semester I'm taking calculus at college and I was looking for websites that have quizzes/test for things like trigonometry, trig formulas, pre-calculus, calculus readiness, etc. so I can get ready this summer. I found the "MU Math Tests Homepage"

http://mathonline.missouri.edu/mucgi-bin/munew.cgi?variable=

The questions at MU aren't that challenging, but I'm looking for sites similar. Any ideas? (other than doing problems from library books).

I know this is isn't a conventional math stack question. I checked with the meta site to see if this was appropriate, so please don't downvote. Thank you:

[Asking for websites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/asking-for-websites)

Comment: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) has some quizzes you can take on various subjects; I don't know if it will be much better than the resource you have though.

Comment: [This also](http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/precalculus.html) seems like it would be a handy resource.

Comment: You can check out [Brilliant.org's practice section](https://brilliant.org/math/algebra/functions/). We are building out the Geometry and Calculus sections, which should be out by the end of the month.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of resources that I enjoy using. First, is Brilliant.org:

http://brilliant.org/

There is a subscription fee but it is worth it. It starts with simple questions on the topics you mentioned and progressively gets harder.

Another site that is good is this quiz page written by Terry Tao:

http://scherk.pbworks.com/w/page/14864181/FrontPage

I can recommend plenty of good books to get you started or advance your knowledge on these topics if you like?